# How to construct a correct accept function for droppable element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have 2 free-draggable `div` elements with absolute positioning. Inside those 2 divs, I have 3 additional draggable `div`s. (I use jQuery and jQuery-UI)

- `Div A` and `Div B`are freely draggable with no direct drop target
  (like windows in Windows OS).
- Green boxes can be dragged and dropped only on another green box. (to be swapped)
- Yellow boxes can be dragged and dropped only on another yellow box. (to be swapped)

I did everything related to drag, drop, swap operations: All good.

The problem is, I couldn't prevent dropping yellow box on green box when `Div A` is over  `Div B`.

What I tried: (but didn't work)

- I added `parent` to draggable's `containment`
- I tried the following function for droppable's `accept`:

  ```
  $(elem).droppable({
      accept: function(draggable){
      if(draggable.parent()!=$(this).parent()){
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  });
  ```

I want to solve this without assigning and comparing ID or CLASS names. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if(draggable.parent()!=$(this).parent())` will never be true, because even if they contain the same DOM element, they're two separate jQuery objects, and separate objects are never `==` to each other. If it's really correct to compare the parents, you could compare the DOM elements, because there will only be the one (even if it's wrapped in more than one jQuery object):

```
if(draggable.parent()[0] != this.parentNode)
```